# permanent data download after AppEventsLogger activateApp

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to measure installs from Mobile App Ads in Facebook, using Facebook SDK 3.21.1. Following the guide from FB, I just added the following line to the onResume method of the activity:

```
com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
```

The measurement works, but looking at DDMS Network Statiatics, I observe a nearly permanent data transfer about 1 KB/s, which even persists, when putting the into background. The result is a corresponding battery and data drain.

I tried deactivating in the onPause method, but didn't stop the data transfer:

```
com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp
```

Is there anything else to do in order to start/stop the measurement?

Comment: I don't think the data transfer is app events related.

Comment: But the data transfer clearly depends on this line. Commenting it out, the data transfer stops.

Comment: The Problem was a side effect of using okhttp v1.1 in my app (which was already implemented long time ago, before using the fb-SDK).
After updating to okhttp v1.6, the data download disappeared.